# Is there a way to edit and save files on an FTP server in Visual Studio 2008+?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, plugins, ftp

I want to create a project and manage the files in Visual Studio 2008 on my computer, but I want VS to upload everything to an FTP server whenever I save the project, so that I can quickly compile and test my program on UNIX.

I have been using BBEdit on my Mac, which has built-in FTP opening and saving, but I want to move over to Visual Studio because I want to use Intellisense.

Is there built-in functionality in Visual Studio for doing this, or a plug-in that I could install? It would really speed up my workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is any Visual Studio Add-in for this purpose. However, you can do this in a post-build operation using the FTP command line option. You can also use this nice free FTP tool - [NcFTP Client](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/) for this purpose. It will push the files into FTP location whenever you build the project. I hope this helps.